# I am trying to copy a directory from slave (remote) to my master (local) machine using ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy a directory from slave (remote) to my master (local) machine using ansible playbook. The directory has my backup data in zip files. but i am getting this error:

This is my playbook

---

- hosts: confluence
  become: true
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: copy

  fetch:

  ```
        src: /home/confluence/atlassian/application-data/confluence/backups/
        dest: /home/webwerks/new
  ```

[image: Console error]

Comment: paste your playbook here

Comment: are you able to ping the server? ansible -m ping servername

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text. Post the text itself, properly formatted.

Comment: ---
- hosts: confluence
  become: true
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: copy
      fetch:

              src: /home/confluence/atlassian/application-data/confluence/backups/
              dest: /home/webwerks/new

Answer (score 0):

The fetch-module can only copy files from remote to local, not folders.

There are several ways to copy folders from remote to local:

- find all files remote with the find-module, build the local folder structure and fetch all files one by one -> very slow
- use the synchronize-module -> rsyncd must be running on remote
- use the local_action-module to run a shell command locally to execute rsync or scp in any way you want